# I need a software to format all HDDs on boot

Tags: hard-disk, boot

Does any of you have a ready solution or knows how to delete all partitions on all HDDs on boot? We install 100 PCs a day and we have to delete partitions before shipping them. At the moment it's time consuming using 3 party software or Windows installer. Any suggestions? I doesn't need to do deep format, literally deleting partitions is enough.

Comment: If you are looking for a tool, please [edit] your question and say so explicitly. If you are looking for a "how-to" that is off-topic here - this is a software recommendation site.

Comment: Umm. Why not simply put a corresponding call to `format` or `fdisk` into autostart (`autoexec.bat` or whatever is the corresponding place with the Windows version you're using)?

Comment: because it has to boot and delete all partitions. Can't do it from Windows level

Comment: Can you elect to boot from e.g. external USB media?

Comment: yes, usb is preferable